# PHP - Echoing a string as a parameter in a JavaScript onclick function

Tags: javascript, php, html, string, echo

I'm trying to echo a string in PHP as a string variable in a JavaScript function. It doesn't output as desired. How do I fix this?

```
<?php
    $example1 = "example 1";
    $example2 = "example 2";
    $example3 = "example 3';
    $string = $example1.", ".$example2.", ".$example3;
    echo "<script>function testFunction(string) {console.log(string);}</script>";
    echo "<button onclick='testFunction(".$string.")'>Test</button>";
?>
```

Desired output: `<button onclick='testFunction("example 1, example 2, example 3")'>Test</button>`

Actual output: `<button onclick='testFunction("example 1"  example 2= example 3=)'>Test</button>`

Comment: Better approach: avoid inline handlers entirely, they're horrendous

Comment: How else should I pass unique data from PHP to a specific button in HTML to execute JavaScript with that data?

Comment: I'd prefer either JSON in a `<script` tag, or data attributes, or a separate network request. How exactly to structure it'll depend on how general the solution needs to be - eg, if you have multiple buttons

Comment: I do have multiple buttons each with it's own unique string parameter. So put a data attribute on the button which corresponds to it's string in the JSON data in a script tag? Or make the data it's data attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Inline handlers are horrible practice. They have very ugly quote escaping issues (that you're running into here) and have a demented scope chain. There should be no reason to use them in modern JavaScript. Consider passing the values to the HTML some other way, and then attaching the handlers properly using JavaScript instead.

For example, you could use data attributes for each button, or you could echo JSON into a script tag that contains the parameters:

```
$button_data = array(
    'example 1, example 2, example 3'
    // add more button data here as needed
);
```

```
<script type="button-data">
<?php echo json_encode($button_data) ?>;
</script>
```

Then read it in JS and attach listeners:

```
const buttonData = document.querySelector('script[type="button-data"]');
// change this selector as needed
// to select only the buttons you care about
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
buttons.forEach((button, i) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    testFunction(buttonData[i]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for doing it.

```
<?php
$example1 = "example 1";
$example2 = "example 2";
$example3 = "example 3";
$string = $example1 . ", " . $example2 . ", " . $example3;
?>
<script>
function testFunction(string)
{
    console.log(string);
}
</script>
<button onclick='testFunction("<?php echo $string; ?>")'>Test</button>
```

Comment: This will break the javascript if the php variable's text contains a single or double quote.

Comment: for that purpose, we need to purify the variable but that was not in the scope of question.